# Can I ask a question comparing two related/similar programming languages?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I want to ask a question about the differences between C and C++, but I'm worried it might not be on-topic. Are questions such as "what are the differences between language x and language y" on topic for this site, where language x and language y share features or are extremely similar?

Comment: That seems like an extremely broad question even if on topic: "What are the differences between apples and chickens?".

Comment: That's true... I'm mostly talking about the differences between similar programming languages. I'll add that to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obligatory link to https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/big-picture#lang-comparisons, which quotes from a section of Bjarne Stroustrup's ["The Design and Evolution of C++"](http://stroustrup.com/dne.html) (emphasis added):

> **[I have] a long-standing and strongly held view [that] Language comparisons are rarely meaningful and even less often fair. A good comparison of major programming languages requires more effort than most people are willing to spend, experience in a wide range of application areas, a rigid maintenance of a detached and impartial point of view, and a sense of fairness.** [...]
>
> I also worry about a phenomenon I have repeatedly observed in honest attempts at language comparisons. The authors try hard to be impartial, but are hopelessly biased by focusing on a single application, a single style of programming, or a single culture among programmers. Worse, when one language is significantly better known than others, a subtle shift in perspective occurs: Flaws in the well-known language are deemed minor and simple workarounds are presented, whereas similar flaws in other languages are deemed fundamental. Often, the workarounds commonly used in the less-well-known languages are simply unknown to the people doing the comparison or deemed unsatisfactory because they would be unworkable in the more familiar language.
>
> Similarly, information about the well-known language tends to be completely up-to-date, whereas for the less-known language, the authors rely on several-year-old information. For languages that are worth comparing, a comparison of language X as defined three years ago vs. language Y as it appears in the latest experimental implementation is neither fair nor informative. [...]

The rest of that ISO C++ wiki page's section on language comparisons is also worth reading (but remember that it is aimed at a particular audience).

If you're going to ask such a question make sure you make the question *highly focused* and *insistently solicit objectivity and depth* in answers.

Answer (score 3):

- Questions about comparing the **design or implementation** of two languages should be on-topic.
- Questions about comparing the **syntax, semantics or usability** of two languages should be off-topic.

For example:

- "What is the difference between arrays in C and Java?" ─ off-topic, because it's about the semantics or usability of arrays in these two languages.
- "Why are arrays length-prefixed in Java but not in C?" ─ on-topic, because it's asking about design decisions made by the designers of these two languages.

Another example:

- "What are the differences between closures in Java and Javascript?" ─ off-topic, because it's asking about the semantics of closures.
- "Why does Java forbid closures from assigning to variables from the outer scope, when other languages such as Javascript allow this?" ─ on-topic, because it's asking about why closures were designed a certain way in Java, and this limitation also has implications for how closures can be implemented.

Essentially, if you're asking how the different languages work because you don't already know, then it's not a design question.